# Which mathematical theory investigates distortions?

Tags: lie-groups, symmetry

For transformations like rotations, translations or boosts **Lie theory** is the appropriate theory. Which theory talks in similar, systematic terms about distortions

$$ M \vec{v} = m \vec{v} \quad \forall \ \vec{v} \quad ?$$

In Lie theory we can learn a lot about certain transformations/symmetries by looking at the corresponding Lie algebra and deriving representations of the transformations in question.

I'm searching for a similar treatment of distortions. Concretely this means looking at infinitesimal elements, deriving the corresponding algebra that encodes the information about the transformation and deriving systematically representations.

I wasn't able to find some "distortion group" and therefore I concluded there must be a good reason for this. Maybe we need here another framework. If it can be done using Lie theory, the correct name of the "distortion group" would help me immensely

Comment: Doesn't Lie theory still encompass that?

Comment: Is $m$ just a scalar? Then you're just doing linear algebra.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes $m$ is just a scalar. Of course things boil down to linear algebra, just as in Lie theory. Nevertheless, Lie theory isn't just linear algebra

Comment: I mean, what do you want to know about scalar multiplication? It would help if your question were more specific.

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow I searched for quite a while for some treatment of distortions using Lie theory, but couldn't find something. If it can be done, the name of the group would be immensly useful

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay I'll expand it

Comment: You might have more luck searching for "dilations" instead of "distortions."

Answer (score 1):

You weren't able to find anything because "distortion" is not a term mathematicians use for scalar multiplication. (I object to the claim that scalar multiplication is a "distortion," anyway; compared to other things you could do to a vector space, scalar multiplication hardly distorts anything at all!)

If I understand your question correctly, you want to understand the structure, Lie algebra, and representation theory of the Lie group $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ of invertible scalars. Another name for this Lie group is the general linear group $\text{GL}_1(\mathbb{R})$. This is a very easy Lie group to understand, since it's $1$-dimensional and therefore abelian. It has two connected components, the positive reals and the negative reals, and the positive reals are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (which is its Lie algebra) via the exponential map

$$\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto e^t \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}_{>0}.$$

Because this group is $1$-dimensional and abelian, its Lie algebra is also $1$-dimensional and abelian, and so there are no interesting Lie brackets.

A finite-dimensional complex representation of the Lie algebra $\mathbb{R}$ is given by a choice of square complex matrix. The classification of representations is the classification of complex matrices up to conjugation, which is described by [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). The classification of real representations is a bit more complicated but can be deduced from the [structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) applied to $\mathbb{R}[x]$ (which should be interpreted in this context as the [universal enveloping algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra) of the Lie algebra $\mathbb{R}$).

There is absolutely no need to go beyond standard linear algebra and Lie theory here. Replacing $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{C}$ is also not an issue.